# How to lookup a value that occurs four times, and retrieve each adjecent cell's value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a sheet that has four separate cells with the value "Sub Total", for four different subtotals, which are stored in an adjacent cell. Here's an example:

```
           $1.00
           $2.50
Sub Total  $3.50

           $5.00
           $20.00
           $10.00
Sub Total  $35.00

           $1.50
Sub Total  $1.50

Sub Total  -
```

The four values will always be in the same order, but they could be in any row below the previous one. I'm trying to copy the adjacent values into another spreadsheet.

How can I reference a specific occurrence of "Sub Total" using a formula? So, for example, copy the first occurrence into cell C1, second occurrence into D1, third occurrence into E1 and fourth occurence into F1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a couple of helper columns. Assume that column A contains your "subtotal" strings, and column B contains your values.

In column C, enter in the following:

`=COUNTIF($A$1:A2, "subtotal")` Mind the "$" in the first reference. Drag that formula down column C, and the range for your COUNTIF will grow, giving you the number of "subtotal" references it has seen so far in column A.

Now, in column D, enter: `=CONCATENATE(A2,C2)`, and drag it down. For your targeted cells, this will produce values like "subtotal1", "subtotal2", etc, whereas for non-target cells, it will just produce values like "1", "2", etc...

Now, anywhere else that you want, you can reference the value (in column B), by the index you've created in column D, as follows: `=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("subtotal1",D:D),1)`.  Replace subtotal1 with whichever subtotal you're looking for.

Comment: Yep. Hiding columns has no effect on formulas referencing them.